# WebSocket and javascript promises

Tags: javascript, websocket, promise

Trying to implement a promises wrapper on top of WebSocket api. And testing on chrome.

```
function WSConnection() {
    'use strict';
    this.socket = {};
}

WSConnection.prototype.connect = function (url) {
    'use strict';

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var this.socket = new WebSocket(url);

        this.socket.onopen = function () {
            socket.send('hello from the client');
            resolve();
        };

        this.socket.onmessage = function (message) {
            console.log("Received on websocket: " + message);
        };

        socket.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('WebSocket error: ' + error);
            reject(error);
        };

        socket.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log("Websocket socket closed: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        };
    });
};


WSConnection.prototype.disconnect = function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log("Disconnect request from local app layer");
    this.socket.close();
};
```

However when I run this, I get exception at

```
        var this.socket = new WebSocket(url);
```

With the error

> "Pause on promise rejection. TyperError: Cannot set property 'socket'
>   of undefined"

. And on the console I see following error -

> "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'socket' of
>   undefined".

What is wrong here? Does "`this.socket`" referring to 'socket' variable in promises object? If so, how can I access the 'socket' variable in the WSConnection object. Is there a better way to promisify websocket apis on the browser?

Comment: Well `this` is undefined in the promise resolver callback.

Comment: I got useful info from the [duplicate link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) provided above. Not sure how to accept it.

Comment: You don't need to accept anything when your question is closed. You should just upvote the helpful answers there.

Comment: You may also be interested in [websocket-as-promised](https://github.com/vitalets/websocket-as-promised) - a ready-to-use Promise-based API for Websockets.

Answer (score 1):

The line with error is in incorrect syntax

`this.socket = new WebSocket(url);`

It should be `this.socket = new WebSocket(url);` I suppose

Also in `new Promise` callback your this will undefined, because it is anonymus callback.

You can `bind` this to callback or ES2015 arrow functions (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044807/passing-scope-to-callback-function-binding))

Example with arrow functions:

```
function WSConnection() {
    'use strict';
    this.socket = {};
}

WSConnection.prototype.connect = function (url) {
    'use strict';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.socket = new WebSocket(url);

        this.socket.onopen = function () {
            socket.send('hello from the client');
            resolve();
        };

        this.socket.onmessage = function (message) {
            console.log("Received on websocket: " + message);
        };

        socket.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('WebSocket error: ' + error);
            reject(error);
        };

        socket.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log("Websocket socket closed: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        };
    });
};


WSConnection.prototype.disconnect = function () {
    'use strict';
    console.log("Disconnect request from local app layer");
    this.socket.close();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue. However the arrow functions are supported only in firefox as of now, I guess

Comment: @sthustfo you can use a transpiler to convert it to ES5 (like babel)